# Add java list entry from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, list, jsp

I have a Spring-MVC project, and in one of my controllers:

I have `List<Long> someIds;`

How to add an entry to this on my JSP page, probably via JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this directly but there is option of using ajax.

Comment: might [help](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: There are many options you can directly fetch them from request.

Comment: create array in javascript and send that object in request.